# Having trouble with x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, macros, x86

I am trying to figure out my error.  To me this program seems correct.  I've added the first two macro's : abin2int and int2abin Also, the sum, min, max and compute average.  The rest are a template.

My error:

> ast06.asm:313: error: memory address expected
>   ast06.asm:425: error: memory address expected
>   ast06.asm:429: error: memory address expected
>   ast06.asm:433: error: memory address expected

It's specifically calling int2abin.  I cant seem to shake this. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
;  Arguments:
;   %1 -> <string>, register -> string address
;   %2 -> <integer>, register -> result


;  Macro usgae
;   abin2int  <string>, <integer>

;  Example usage:
;   abin2int    rbx, tmpInteger

;  For example, to get address into a local register:
;       mov rsi, %1

;  Note, the register used for the macro call (rbx in this example)
;  must not be altered before the address is copied into
;  another register (if desired).

%macro  abin2int    2

mov ebx, %1     ; Index
mov rax, 0      ; rSum
mov ecx, 1

%%binLP: 
movzx   r8d, byte[rbx] ; getChr
cmp r8d, NULL      ; r8b == NULL
je  %%exitQLP
sub r8d, "0"    ; IntVal
mul ecx     ; rSum = rSum * 4
add eax, r8d    ; rSum + IntVal
inc ebx
jmp %%binLP

%%exitQLP:  
mov dword[%2], eax


%endmacro



; =====================================================================
;  Macro to convert integer to hex value in ASCII format.
;  Reads <integer>, converts to ASCII/binary string including
;   NULL into <string>
;  Note, macro should preserve any registers that the macro alters.

;  Arguments:
;   %1 -> <integer>, value
;   %2 -> <string>, string address

%macro  int2abin    2

mov eax, dword[%1]
mov ecx, 4
mov r9d, STRLENGTH
mov r10d, STRLENGTH
dec r9d
dec r10d
mov r11, 0

%%intLP:
mov edx, 0
cmp r9d, 0
je  %%int2LP
cdq
div ecx
push    rdx
dec r9d
jmp %%intLP

%%int2LP:
cmp r10d, 0
je  %%null
pop rax
add al, "0"
mov byte[%2+r11], al
inc al
inc r11
dec r10d
jmp %%int2LP

%%null:
mov byte[%2+r11], al


%endmacro

; =====================================================================
;  Simple macro to display a string to the console.
;  Count characters (excluding NULL).
;  Display string starting at address <stringAddr>

;  Macro usage:
;   printString  <stringAddr>

;  Arguments:
;   %1 -> <stringAddr>, string address

%macro  printString 1
push    rax         ; save altered registers
push    rdi
push    rsi
push    rdx
push    rcx

lea rdi, [%1]       ; get address
mov rdx, 0          ; character count
%%countLoop:
cmp byte [rdi], NULL
je  %%countLoopDone
inc rdi
inc rdx
jmp %%countLoop
%%countLoopDone:

mov rax, SYS_write      ; system call for write (SYS_write)
mov rdi, STDOUT     ; standard output
lea rsi, [%1]       ; address of the string
syscall             ; call the kernel

pop rcx         ; restore registers to original values
pop rdx
pop rsi
pop rdi
pop rax
%endmacro

; =====================================================================
;  Initialized variables.

section .data

; -----
;  Define standard constants.

TRUE        equ 1
FALSE       equ 0

SUCCESS     equ 0           ; successful operation
NOSUCCESS   equ 1           ; unsuccessful operation

STDIN       equ 0           ; standard input
STDOUT      equ 1           ; standard output
STDERR      equ 2           ; standard error

SYS_read    equ 0           ; system call code for read
SYS_write   equ 1           ; system call code for write
SYS_open    equ 2           ; system call code for file open
SYS_close   equ 3           ; system call code for file close
SYS_fork    equ 57          ; system call code for fork
SYS_exit    equ 60          ; system call code for terminate
SYS_creat   equ 85          ; system call code for file open/create
SYS_time    equ 201         ; system call code for get time

LF      equ 10
SPACE       equ " "
NULL        equ 0
ESC     equ 27

NUMS_PER_LINE   equ 2


; -----
;  Assignment #6 Provided Data

STRLENGTH   equ 32

cSides      db  "00000000000000000000000010101001", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000000001010101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000000101011001", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000000000101010", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000010101101011", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000001010100101101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000000101101101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000101011111000", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000111100111001", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000001001111001101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000001110001111101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000101111100000", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000110011111001", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000011101001000101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000000011101011101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000010110011111000", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000001110101111101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000001010001111101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000011110001111101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000001010001101101", NULL
    db  "00000000000000000001100001111101", NULL

aLength     db  "00000000000000000000000000010101", NULL
length      dd  0

cubeAreasSum    dd  0
cubeAreasAve    dd  0
cubeAreasMin    dd  0
cubeAreasMax    dd  0

; -----
;  Misc. variables for main.

hdr     db  LF, "-----------------------------------------------------"
    db  LF, ESC, "[1m", "CS 218 - Assignment #6", ESC, "[0m", LF
    db  "Cube Area Information", LF, LF
    db  "Cube Sides's:", LF, NULL
shdr        db  LF, "Cube Area's Sum:   ", NULL
avhdr       db  LF, "Cube Areas's Ave:  ", NULL
minhdr      db  LF, "Cube Areas's Min:  ", NULL
maxhdr      db  LF, "Cube Areas's Max:  ", NULL

tmpInteger  dd  0
newLine     db  LF, NULL
spaces      db  "   ", NULL

; Additional variables (if any)

conSix      dd  6

; =====================================================================
;  Uninitialized variables

section .bss

cubeAreas   resd    21
tempString  resb    33

; **************************************************************

section .text
global  _start
_start:

; -----
;  Display assignment initial headers.

mov edx, 0
printString hdr

; -----
;  Convert integer length, in ASCII binary format



;       Convert ASCII binary format length to integer (no macro)
;       Do not use macro here...

mov rbx, aLength    ; Index
mov rax, 0      ; rSum
mov ecx, 1

calc: 
movzx   r8d, byte[rbx] ; getChr
cmp r8d, NULL      ; r8b == NULL
je  exitLP
sub r8d, "0"    ; IntVal
mul ecx     ; rSum = rSum * 4
add eax, r8d    ; rSum + IntVal
inc rbx
jmp calc

exitLP: 
mov dword[length], eax

; -----
;  Convert cube sides from ASCII/binary to integer

mov ecx, dword [length]
mov rdi, 0                  ; index for cube areas
mov rbx, cSides
cvtLoop:
abin2int    rbx, tmpInteger

mov eax, dword [tmpInteger]
mul eax
mov r10, 6
mul r10d
mov dword [cubeAreas+rdi*4], eax
add ebx, (STRLENGTH+1)

inc rdi
dec ecx
cmp ecx, 0
jne cvtLoop

; -----
;  Display each the cube area (two per line).

mov ecx, dword [length]
mov rsi, 0
printLoop:
int2abin    dword [cubeAreas+rsi*4], tempString
printString tempString
printString spaces

test    rsi, 1              ; even/odd check
je  skipNewline
printString newLine
skipNewline:
inc rsi
dec ecx
cmp ecx, 0
jne printLoop
printString newLine

; -----
;  Find sum, min, max and compute average.


;cubeAreas[ i] = 6 * sides[ i]* sides[i]
mov ecx, dword[length]
mov rsi, 0

Calc:
movzx eax, byte[cSides+rsi]
movzx ebx, byte[cSides+rsi]     
mul ebx
mul byte[conSix]
mov dword[cubeAreas+rsi*4],eax

inc rsi
dec ecx
cmp ecx,0
jne Calc

;  Sum, min, and max

mov eax, word[cubeAreas]
mov word[cubeAreasMin], eax
mov word[cubeAreasMax], eax

mov ecx, dword[length]
mov rsi, 0

SLatLP:
mov eax, dword[cubeAreas+rsi*4]
add dword[cubeAreasSum], eax
cmp eax, dword[cubeAreasMin]
jae notNewCaMin
mov dword[cubeAreasMin], eax

notNewCaMin:
cmp eax, dword[cubeAreasMax]
jbe notNewCaMax
mov dword[cubeAreasMax], eax

notNewCaMax:

inc rsi
dec ecx
cmp ecx, 0
jne SLatLP

;  Average
mov eax, dword[cubeAreasSum]
mov edx, 0
div dword[length]
mov dword[cubeAreasAve], eax

; -----
;  Convert sum to ASCII/binary for printing.

printString shdr

mov eax, dword[cubeAreasSum]
mov ecx, 4
mov r9d, STRLENGTH
mov r10d, STRLENGTH
dec r9d
dec r10d
mov r11, 0

int1LP:
mov edx, 0
cmp r9d, 0
je  int2LP
cdq
div ecx
push    rdx
dec r9d
jmp int1LP

int2LP:
cmp r10d, 0
je  nulltime
pop     rax
add al, "0"
mov byte[tempString+r11], al
inc al
inc r11
dec r10d
jmp int2LP

nulltime:
mov byte[tempString+rsi], al




; -----
;  Convert average, min, and max integers to ASCII/binary for printing.

printString avhdr
int2abin    dword [cubeAreasAve], tempString
printString tempString

printString minhdr
int2abin    dword [cubeAreasMin], tempString
printString tempString

printString maxhdr
int2abin    dword [cubeAreasMax], tempString
printString tempString

printString newLine
printString newLine


; *****************************************************************
;  Done, terminate program.

last:
mov rax, SYS_exit
mov rbx, SUCCESS
syscall
```

Comment: Which assembler are you using? TASM? NASM? YASM? And the code you provided doesn't even have 433 lines: the errors are reported on lines `313`, `425`, `429` and `433`. Without some indication of where these lines are in your code, it makes it difficult for us!

Comment: That's a lot of code you expect us to look at. Before you ask a question, it is a good idea to try to narrow down the problem as much as possible. Have a look at our tutorial: [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** If you're using NASM, then you've got a problem with your `int2abin` macro. It starts:

```
%macro  int2abin    2

mov eax, dword[%1]
```

but when you call it, you use

```
int2abin    dword [cubeAreas+rsi*4], tempString
...
int2abin    dword [cubeAreasAve], tempString
```

That duplicates the square brackets (`[]`) - so I'd change the macro to:

```
mov eax, %1
```

---

Your code has the following line:

```
add al, "0"
```

In most assemblers, using double quotes (`"`) implies a string that needs to be stored in memory somewhere - so the above would be trying to add the value of the contents of some memory somewhere to `al`.

You probably wanted:

```
add al, '0'
```

The single quotes (`'`) mean a character literal - the ASCII value 48 - which is what you want to add to `al`.

Comment: I believe that with NASM double quotes will work. It will convert the character sequence into a value. If you were to move `"0123"` into _EAX_ it should pack them and yield `0x33323130`. `"0"` should produce 0x30.

Comment: @Michael Did I mention that I dislike NASM? Thanks for that: I looked a little deeper...

Comment: if I get a segmentation fault inbetween prinitng the                            int2abin dword[cubeAreas+rsi*4], tempString what could that mean?  Im guessing my int2abin is still messing up somewhere inbetween

Comment: A segmentation fault could come from a number of areas: Why are you dividing by `ecx` - when `ecx` holds the number `4` rather than `10`? Why are you storing `al` as the last statement of the macro, when `al` holds an increment of the final character rather than NUL? Why do you have identical (incorrect) code in `printString` rather than invoking the macro? You really need to step through this code with a debugger; watch what it is doing at every step, and above all work out why it's doing it.